# AWS Java SDK - Timeout waiting for connection from pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection-pooling, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I am working with AmazonSQS. I am using threads to read content from there, after a short time, I get the connection pool error

this is my thread logic

```
ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest(#url);
request.setMaxNumberOfMessages(#getMaxMessagesPolled);
request.setWaitTimeSeconds(5);
while (true) {
  List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
  try {
    messages = awsService.getMessages(parameters, request);
  } catch (Exception clientException) {
  continue;
  }
  for (Message message : messages) {
      //process
      awsService.removeMessage(parameters, message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

error :

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
```

As I know the default connection pool size is 50. I do not have >50 threads.

Thanks

Comment: Did you close your S3 objects?

Comment: I do not use any S3Object

Comment: Can we see a snippet of the code which may be causing your errors?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Do you really (1) allocate an ArrayList to have it immediately thrown away and (2) completely ignore exceptions?  The exceptions may be showing something else.

Comment: @javagc Were you able to resolve? I am getting the same issue.